# Передача base64 строки с сервера на клиент

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, base64

Есть приложение mvc. На странице есть `<input id="fileLoader" type="file" />`. В него пользователь загружает изображение. С помощью js на клиенте я перевожу картинку в base64 последовательность и отображаю в img. Далее передаю эту последовательность на сервер. И там перевожу в массив байт и записываю в базу. Теперь мне необходимо считать из базы массив байт и передать назад на страницу и отобразить в img. Но при попытке передать base64 строку на клиент вылетает ошибка.
Вот мой код который делает всё вышеописанное:
Клиент:

```
//Добавление нового автомобиля
    $('#modalWindow').on('click', '#btnConfirm', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/_AddNewCar",
            data: $('form').serialize() + "&base64img=" + $('#autoPicture').attr('src'),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    //Изменение содержимого загружаемого файла
    $('#modalWindow').on('change', '#fileLoader', function () {
        ReadImageUrl(this);
    });

    function ReadImageUrl(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#autoPicture').attr('src', '');
        }
    }
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public String _AddNewCar(Car car, string base64img)
        {
            var base64arr = base64img.Split(',');

            byte[] picture = Convert.FromBase64String(base64arr[1]);

            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(picture);

            return result;
        }
```

В этом примере я не пишу в базу, а просто пытаюсь отправить сразу же назад base64 строку для более короткого примера. Вот ошибка которая вылетает на консоле клиента:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно передать изображение из контроллера на клиент? Может не обязательно в виде base64?

Comment: Вообще у вас изначально решение странное. Обычно файлы передают бинарно, хранят как файл в файловой системе, а в БД хранят линк "куда положили". А клиенту отдают всего лишь линк.

Comment: @Movs необходимо такое решение. Осталось передать картинку назад на клиент каким нибудь способом.

Comment: Вообще ошибка про то, что слишком длинный УРЛ. Точно POST делаете а не GET? Такое ощущение что весь ваш base64 пишет в строку GET запроса...

Comment: @Movs ну вы же в коде видите что post.

Comment: Вообще, конечно вот это $('#autoPicture').attr('src') содержит строку вида "http://site.com/image.jpg" а не base64 от картинки. И в контроллер вы тут передаете именно такую строку (ее б хотябы urlencode сделать..).  И потом это же свойство пытаетесь установить, передав туда base64.

Comment: @Movs Там, судя, по тексту вопроса, строка вида `"data:image/jpg;base64;..."`

Comment: @Yaant вы правы, я думал это из кода видно что я в src записываю base64 представление изображения.

Comment: @Movs по поводу get запроса вы были правы, хоть у меня везде и написано post. Но когда контроллер возвращает результат в ajax запрос, и пытается считать строку вернувшуюся сыпется эта ошибка именно с припиской get, почему так происходит? Я ведь на сервер посылаю post запрос.